# AndEngine - removing a particular Sprite & Its body

Tags: java, android, andengine

I would like to remove the body when the item is clicked. As you see i have it set up as a wallfixture.

When the item is clicked the sprite is removed, now i just would like to remove the body also..

```
public void addSprites(Scene scene, int x,int y,int width,int height,String type,Body body){
    Sprite sprite = null;

    if(type.equals(TAG_ENTITY_ATTRIBUTE_TYPE_VALUE_WOOD)) {
        sprite = new Sprite(x, y, width, height, this.wood, this.getVertexBufferObjectManager()){
            @Override
            public boolean onAreaTouched(final TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent, final float pTouchAreaLocalX, final float pTouchAreaLocalY) {
                mScene.detachChild(this);
                mPhysicsWorld.destroyBody(woodBody);
                return true;
            }

        };
           final FixtureDef wallFixtureDef = PhysicsFactory.createFixtureDef(0, 0.5f, 0.5f);
          woodBody =  PhysicsFactory.createBoxBody(this.mPhysicsWorld, sprite, BodyType.StaticBody, wallFixtureDef);
             mScene.registerTouchArea(sprite);
        Log.e("TYPE", "Wood");
    }
    scene.attachChild(sprite);
            }
```

What i want to do is when the item is clicked i would like to remove the sprite & the body it is attached to. The code i have works but the only problem is it removes ALL of the bodies, i use the method to attach items to a level, so its a total of 3 items, and when one is clicked the body is removed from ALL of the sprites, when it should just be the one clicked.

Anyone know how to go about doing this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am not sure but probably that happens because you use the same variable for all bodies

```
woodBody =  PhysicsFactory.createBoxBody(this.mPhysicsWorld, sprite, BodyType.StaticBody, wallFixtureDef);
```

To do good connection between body and sprite I suggest you to extend Sprite and declare body variable inside your class. For example I do this in that way

```
public class Ball extends Sprite{

final FixtureDef ballFixtureDef = PhysicsFactory.createFixtureDef(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, false, Main.CATEGORYBIT_BALL, Main.MASKBITS_BALL, (short)0);

Body body;
float velocityX, velocityY; 
int type;   

public Ball(float pX, float pY, TextureRegion pTextureRegion, PhysicsWorld pWorld, float velocityX, float velocityY, int type) 
{
    super(pX, pY, pTextureRegion);
    this.type = type;
    this.velocityX = velocityX;
    this.velocityY = velocityY;
    body = PhysicsFactory.createCircleBody(pWorld, this, BodyType.DynamicBody, ballFixtureDef);
    body.setUserData(Ball.this);
    pWorld.registerPhysicsConnector(new PhysicsConnector(this, body, true, true));
}
}
```

and method for destroy sprite with body

```
private void destroyBall(final Ball ball)
    {
        this.runOnUpdateThread(new Runnable(){

            @Override
            public void run() {

                final Body body = ball.body;
                mPhysicsWorld.unregisterPhysicsConnector(mPhysicsWorld.getPhysicsConnectorManager().findPhysicsConnectorByShape(ball));
                mPhysicsWorld.destroyBody(body);
                mScene.detachChild(ball);
                ballsList.remove(ball);
            }});

    }
```

and you just create object in that way

```
Ball b = new Ball(float pX, float pY, TextureRegion pTextureRegion, PhysicsWorld pWorld, float velocityX, float velocityY, int type) 
{
    @Override
    public boolean onAreaTouched(final TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent, final float pTouchAreaLocalX, final float pTouchAreaLocalY)
    {
        destroyBall(this);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not exactly sure, but I think you need to flag items or objects that need to be removed first.  Then when the game updates it should go through all of the objects and check which ones are flagged and then remove them.  I'm new to this too but here goes nothing:

So a good way to do this in AndEngine is to first make an IUpdateHandler like so:

```
/**
* This wil get called every frame and is placed inside of your
* main game activity or where ever you want.
**/
public IUpdateHandler getCollisionUpdateHandler(){

    return new IUpdateHandler(){

         @Override
         public void onUpdate(float pSecondsElapsed) {

             // loop through all of your sprites
             for(int i=0; i<GameActivity.this.spriteList.length; i++) {

                  //if sprite is flagged for deletion, begin removal
                  if( GameActivity.this.spriteList.get(i).isDelete()){
                       // get the next sprite to delete
                       final mSprite Object = GameActivity.this.spriteList.get(i);
                       // can remove it from the list now
                       Game.this.spriteList.remove(i); 

                       final Scene scene = GameActivity.this.mEngine.getScene();
                       final Body body = GameActivity.this.mPhysicsWorld.getPhysicsConnectorManager().findBodyByShape(Object);
                       mPhysicsWorld.destroyBody(body);
                       //scene.getLayer(0).removeEntity(Object);
                       //scene.getLayer(1).removeEntity(Object);
                       scene.detachChild( Object );
                  }
               }
           }
      }
 }
```

Then simply register that update handler. Like so:

```
mScene.registerUpdateHandler( this.getCollisionUpdateHandler() );
```

So now whenever you want to delete a sprite (when it's pressed) then you simply change your method to:

```
@Override
public boolean onAreaTouched(final TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent, final float  pTouchAreaLocalX, final float pTouchAreaLocalY) {
    MainActivity.spriteList.add( this );
    this.delete = true;
    return true;
}
```

Hope that helps.  Here's where I got it from: (I simply tried to make it fit your problem :) )

www.andengine.org/forums/tutorials/box2d-collision-and-removal-t523.html